# use outside repository in intellij-idea

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm wondering if it's possible to use a folder/package/repository in multiple project at the same time without simply copy paste it.

For example :

```
Project 1 has Package A & B
Project 2 has Package A & C
Project 3 has Package A & D
```

Can I take the A Package outside of my 3 projects and create a link to this folder inside my 3 packages like a library & look like this

```
Folder A
Project 1 has Package B and a link to A
Project 2 has Package C and a link to A
Project 3 has Package D and a link to A
```

So my Package B,C & D that are using objects from A without issue but If I want to make a change on A in don't have to copy/paste or push/pull on the all the other projects that use A

Comment: I would advise against this.  This is what Maven is for.

Comment: You should be more specific. What language? Do you want projects as modules? What do you mean about "linking folders"?

Comment: Sounds like you need to understand maven dependencies and how they work..... all this is handled automatically for you with the project object model.

Comment: Yes, use a real build tool.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for code-reuse. The code you put into a dedicated package is some kind of library that you'd like to use in different projects. As indicated in @duffymo's comment you should split this code you want to re-use into a dedicated project, and include this project as a library. For that you can use systems like Maven, or just create a JAR file and manually add it to the classpath.

In other words, before you find a (crude) way to make things work, please take a step back and consider a "good" solution.

Comment: Good build tooling options include Maven, Gradle, and even Ant+Ivy - and probably a handful of lesser-used alternatives (just providing a broader list).